# HTTP 418 while automining Unicoins

Tags: unicoins

Clicking rocks is fun, but I wanted to automate the process of mining unicoins.

I found the following code while googling for ["Satoshi Nakamoto"](http://p2pfoundation.ning.com/profile/SatoshiNakamoto). It will exploit a flaw in the Unicoin protocol called ["rock malleability"](http://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/news/malleability-bankrupt-mt-gox/2014/03/27). Somehow, [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) are used as well.

It's easy to use, just bring up your developer's console in Chrome and enter the following:

```
setInterval(
    function(){
        $.get(
            "/unicoin/rock?_=" + String(new Date().getTime()),
            function(rainbowTable){
                $.post(
                    "/unicoin/mine?rock=" + rainbowTable.rock,
                    {"fkey": $("#fkey").val()},
                    function(malleableRock){
                        console.log(
                            "Mined " + malleableRock.value + " unicoin(s)");
                    }
                )
            }
        )
    }, 11000)
```

The problem is that I'm getting an HTTP error -- [HTTP 418](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2324) to be specific. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a duplicate of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185426/stack-overflow-returning-http-error-code-418-im-a-teapot) on Meta.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a UserScript that automatically mines Unicoins while you browse Stack Exchange sites:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name UnicoinHax
// @namespace http://stackexchange.com
// @description Constantly gives you Unicoins whenever you visit a Stack Exchange site
// @include http://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include https://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include http://*.serverfault.com/*
// @include https://*.serverfault.com/*
// @include http://*.superuser.com/*
// @include https://*.superuser.com/*
// @include http://stackapps.com/*
// @include https://stackapps.com/*
// @include http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include http://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @include https://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @version 1
// @grant none
// ==/UserScript==

//You can also just copy this code and paste it into the console on any page where the domain is a Stack Exchange site:

var hackMeSomeUnicoins = function(myFkey) {
  console.log("Unicoin hacking begun!");
  window.setInterval(function() {
    $.get(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/unicoin/rock", function( data ) {
      var rockId = data.rock;
      $.post(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/unicoin/mine?rock=" + rockId, {fkey: myFkey})
      .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  }, 11000);
};
hackMeSomeUnicoins(StackExchange.options.user.fkey);
```

[Github link](https://github.com/TheGuywithTheHat/SE-random-stuff/blob/master/Unicoins/UnicoinsHax.js).

It is based heavily off of [this](https://gist.github.com/alias1/9905949) script by alais1.

Comment: "Suspicious request

Sorry, your request could not be completed because it looked suspicious. If you meant to perform an action on Stack Overflow, please return to the previous page and try again."

Comment: @AndréLaszlo _Did_ you try it again?

Comment: Yes. [It returns "418 I'm a teapot"](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2324)

Comment: Works for me. Have you been unkind to The Unicorns @AndréLaszlo ?